# How can i serialize a nested PersistentEntityResource in a non persistent entity

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

I want a nested `PersistentEntityResource` to be serialized inside of a non persistent entity. The Resource is being serialized when its returned without being nested so there is probably not a Problem in that entity.

This is a dummy of the entity im trying to return + the nested classes of that including the persistent entity

```
class ReturnedEntityDummy {
    List<resourceWrapperDummy> dummy

    ReturnedEntityDummy(List<resourceWrapperDummy> versions){
        this.dummy = dummy
    }
}
```

```
class resourceWrapperDummy<T> {
    PersistentEntityResource content
    Integer position

    resourceWrapperDummy(PersistentEntityResource content, Integer position) {
        this.content = content
        this.position = position
    }
}
```

The `PersistentEntityResource` inside of the last class is the one i want to be serialized and
this is the error message im getting when i try to return the `ReturnedEntityDummy`:

`Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Failed to specialize base type org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentEntity<java.lang.Object,org.springframework.data.mapping.PersistentProperty<java.lang.Object>> as org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl, problem: Type parameter #2/2 differs;`